# Wrong view on startup, and error while installing android application

Tags: android, eclipse, installation, launch

A few difficulties i am experiencing using eclipse and running my application.
First of all, when i am trying to run the code having selected default activity in the setup menu, it opens the alltravelsview instead of the login view. The login in view is the only view which appears if i select a specific view to start. and it launches correctly then.

Secondly, if i try to install the application on my mobile phone, it appears to install correctly but when i click the button(launcher) i get the message application not installed. I used the export function of the eclipse/adt and it is signed with a private key.

Here a code snippet, i excluded a few activities which are just declarations to shorten it a bit. This code is from the manifest.xml where i suppose the error is made. in my activities i inflate the corresponding views.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.kit.teco.easyTravel.view"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />


    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application

        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" 
        android:permission="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS"
        >
        <activity
            android:name="de.kit.teco.easyTravel.view.LoginView"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <!-- Four lines for login -->
           <!-- Start Login  -->
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <!-- End Login -->
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="de.kit.teco.easyTravel.view.MainMenuView"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main_menu_view" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="de.kit.teco.easyTravel.view.AllTravelsView"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_all_travels_view" >
        </activity>

<--- a few more activities ---->

    </application>

</manifest>
```

EDIT:

the proguard-project.txt:

```
# To enable ProGuard in your project, edit project.properties
# to define the proguard.config property as described in that file.
#
# Add project specific ProGuard rules here.
# By default, the flags in this file are appended to flags specified
# in ${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
# You can edit the include path and order by changing the ProGuard
# include property in project.properties.
#
# For more details, see
#   http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/proguard.html

# Add any project specific keep options here:

# If your project uses WebView with JS, uncomment the following
# and specify the fully qualified class name to the JavaScript interface
# class:
#-keepclassmembers class fqcn.of.javascript.interface.for.webview {
#   public *;
#}
```

the project.properties:

```
# This file is automatically generated by Android Tools.
# Do not modify this file -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE ERASED!
#
# This file must be checked in Version Control Systems.
#
# To customize properties used by the Ant build system edit
# "ant.properties", and override values to adapt the script to your
# project structure.
#
# To enable ProGuard to shrink and obfuscate your code, uncomment this (available properties: sdk.dir, user.home):
#proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt

# Project target.
target=android-17
```

Both look fairly empty, haven't done anything with them, so it is just the autogenereated file. For thrid party libraries i am using:
db40
sidemenu
restlet
and three more used with restlet together

Comment: if You have this apk allready installed, uninstall it before install it again. Could You show a little bit of Your code?

Comment: the apk is not installed. it works when i run it directly from eclipse onto the device but not when I export it and try to install the apk.

For the code, what part of the code do you want to see, hence it is already fairly complex

Comment: are You using any third libraries? If You get problems after signing the apk, maybe there is something wrong with the proguard configuration. Is Proguard config enabled?

Comment: yes i am using a few third libraries. The problem jsut occurs when istalling on the device. It appears to be installed propperly, but as soon as i click the launcher icon i get the message application not installed. Where do i enable proguard configs?

Comment: The thing is, if You install it directly on device, the apk is not signed, also not obfuscated. It seems that proguard is obfuscating some third party libraries that You need on start. There must be a proguard.cfg file in Your project, what we need to know is which third lib You are using. It will be helpful also, if You post Your Activity that starts and the proguard.cfg file.

Comment: all i could find was a proguard-project.txt, but i cant find a cfg file for proguard

Comment: thats the wright file. Proguard changed this with the new 4.7 version but it is the same file, so You can post it.

Comment: posted in original post

Comment: ok there is nothing defined in the config file. Also Your proguard is not enabled, because in the project properties it is not set. There must be another error. After You have do some changes, have You tried to clean Your project in eclipse?

Comment: got to the stage to be able to install, 
android:permission="android.permission.INJECT_EVENTS"
this line messed it up. still the part why it is not starting the launch activity and the other one instead

Comment: ok I think You have to show us this two activities. You could remove the code from proguard..